# import excel file in JTable using java

Tags: java, swing, excel, jtable, jfilechooser

I want that when button is clicked using `JFileChooser`, `filedialog` need to be opened and when excel file is selected it need to be loaded in `JTable`
can anyone please help how to import excel file into `jtable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some use useful links/tutorial for you to use.

[Importing Excel (.xls) in Java Swing application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306661/importing-excel-xls-in-java-swing)

[blog](http://niravjavadeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/01/import-excel-data-into-jtable.html)

There are a couple of open source libraries which you can use to read an excel file such as [Apache POI.](http://poi.apache.org/)

Once you've read your excel file into some data structure, this can be written into a `DataModel` for a `JTable`. Alternatively, you could write a custom `DataModel` which will read dynamically from the excel file, but I'd take the two steps separately and build up the complexity once you understand the excel file reading library you choose.

Comment: thank you alpesh..i have already gone through nirav's blog but code that is available is too much confusing...so if you can, then is there any simple method to achieve it..?